# How to implement streaming in ios app for webcam xcode project

Tags: live-streaming, ip-camera

i'm creating a project for iPhone/iPad to see ipcams live streaming. At the moment i'm using VideoStreamSDK but it has some limitations. I thought to use/implement VLCKit inside my app to stream but i read that it is not a good choice. So my question is: how can i visualize the mjpeg video of an ipcam in live?  Do have i to use the http live streaming guide lines of Apple https://developer.apple.com/streaming/?Can i use a MPMoviePlayerController?
Thank's in advance